# bad_alloc in std::vector constructor

Tags: c++, vector, stl

`std::vector` has a constructor where passing a single argument of `size_type count` should size the vector with `count` default-constructed elements. But the following code fails with a `bad_alloc` exception after a bad conversion:

```
#include <vector>

struct Inner {
  int foo;
  char buf[256];
};

template <typename Type>
struct Outer
{
  typedef std::vector<Inner> BufContainer;
  typedef typename BufContainer::size_type BufIndex;
  BufContainer bufs1;
  BufContainer bufs2;
  const BufIndex BUFCOUNT = 32;

  Outer() :
    bufs1(32),       // fine
    bufs2(BUFCOUNT)  // bad_alloc
  { }
};

int main() {
  Outer<int> outer;
}
```

When I look in the debugger, I can see an incorrect conversion has occurred on that second vector constructor:

```
#13 0x0000000000400bf1 in Outer<int>::Outer (this=0x7ffdc59570c0) at wtf.cc:22
22          bufs2(BUFCOUNT)
(gdb) down
#12 0x0000000000400d6e in std::vector<Inner, std::allocator<Inner> >::vector     (this=0x7ffdc59570d8, __n=140727918359008, __a=...) at /usr/local/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_vector.h:278
278       : _Base(__n, __a)
(gdb) list
273        *  This constructor fills the %vector with @a __n default
274        *  constructed elements.
275        */
276       explicit
277       vector(size_type __n, const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
278       : _Base(__n, __a)
279       { _M_default_initialize(__n); }
(gdb) print __n
$1 = 140727918359008
```

`std::vector::size_type` is simply a typedef from `size_t`. I don't understand why my defined constant `BUFCOUNT` results in that rolled-around value inside the constructor, and would appreciate anyone helping me find the obvious thing I'm missing.

Comment: (1) Copy/paste your MCVE into Coliru; (2) Read [the warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ab145307e84b9a2); (3) ?? (4) all teh profitz

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`BUFCOUNT` is not `static`, which means it's an instance data member (just like `bufs1`, `bufs2`, etc. Non-static data members are initialised in the order of their declaration within the class. This means that `bufs1` and `bufs2` will be initialised *before* `BUFCOUNT`. The initialisation of `bufs2` therefore uses the as-yet-unitialised value of `BUFCOUNT` (in other words, has Undefined Behaviour).

Since it makes zero sense to have each `Outer` object store the same `BUFCOUNT` integer inside it, you might want to make `BUFCOUNT` static.

Comment: I knew it would be something straightforward. I need another cup of coffee. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm surprised that your compiler didn't [warn you about this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ab145307e84b9a2), @John. Do you have your warnings turned off for some reason?

Comment: I'm surprised, too. I just ran it again under gcc 4.9.1 and 5.3.0 with -Wall and -pedantic and they were silent. Clang 8.1.0 found it, though.

Comment: Why would that cause an error in the allocator? `BUFCOUNT`'s value is junk from the stack rather than an intended value `32`, why does the allocator care? Sure, it's UB in theory but in practice there's no way for `std::vector<Inner>(size_type)` to know argument #1 is uninitialised memory, right?

Comment: @cat The junk from the stack is a huge number, so the allocator simply runs out of memory trying to satisfy the request. This is what `bad_alloc` means, after all. (Of course, it could also by chance be a small number, in which case there would not be an immediate error.)

Comment: @JohnS I'm not sure if it would matter, but there is also `-Wextra` flag.

Comment: @ArneVogel I suppose a rough estimate

Comment: @JohnS: Beware with gcc, a number of the `unused` warnings are performed during optimizations analyses and therefore only run when building with some optimizations on. On the other hand, in Clang warnings and optimizations are independent, thus you get the full benefit of all warnings even at `-O0`.

Comment: Troublingly, adding `-O3` to the gcc builds doesn't change the outcome, still gives a clean build. Now I'm wondering if my compiler builds are sane.